# Error validating exception when using System.Reflection

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, validationerror, sandbox-solution

We're developing a SharePoint webpart as a sandboxed solution in Visual Studio 2013 for SharePoint Online. We use an external dll library `iTextSharp` for reading and writing to PDF. We are having a problem when activating our solution.

Our error message is:

> Error validating assembly `itextsharp.dll`.

This solution references prohibited type `System.Reflection.BindingFlags` and cannot be used on this site collection.

Answer (score 1):

You've answered this question yourself already:

> This solution references prohibited type
>   System.Reflection.BindingFlags and cannot be used on this site
>   collection.

You can't use the `System.Reflection` namespace with SharePoint Online solutions (for the most part). The only allowed members from `System.Reflection` are:

- GetValue Name
- GetCustomAttributes
- PropertyType
- GetValue SetValue

I recommend taking a look at Microsoft's documentation for developing SharePoint Online solutions ([link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg454741(v=office.14).aspx)) as there are quite a few namespaces previously available for SharePoint development that are now prohibited.

Here's what Microsoft has to say about this:

> Because it is a multi-tenant environment, when you upload a sandboxed
>   solution to the Solution Gallery, SharePoint Online performs a further
>   round of validation checks, in addition to those performed by
>   on-premise SharePoint installations. A sandboxed solution cannot be
>   activated if it contains code calling any of the following namespaces:

And here's the list of prohibited namespaces (see documentation for all exceptions):

- Microsoft.SqlServer
- Microsoft.Win32
- System.Data.Sql
- System.Data.SqlClient
- System.Data.SqlTypes
- System.IO.Pipes
- System.IO.Ports
- System.Reflection
- System.Runtime.InteropServices
- System.Runtime.Remoting
- System.Threading
- Array.CreateInstance()
- System.Delegate
- Type.GetType(String)
- Type.InvokeMember()